# Problems with script to instance a VM (Compute Engine) on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to instance a VM on Google Cloud Platform through a GoLang script using "libretto" library, but I have always the same error: "googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: Not Found" and I don't understand why.
I downloaded json key file from GCP. 
Is it scopes?

---

This is the code...I'm searching the error on internet but no results...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, and without your code it's hard to know the exact issue. However, I'll give my best shot at answering this.

There's likely two points of failure. This could be related to you incorrectly inputting info within your script, or could be a Libretto related issue (they do list GCP as a support provider).

I did find this issue (https://github.com/apcera/libretto/issues/111) referencing GCP init support that looks related to your issue.